# ByteArrayOutputStream. ToString() does not get any charset

Tags: java

I have written a simple code to print the output of console to a BytreArrayOutputStream. I am using JDK 1.7. However when I want the buffer to a String, I can't use the method BytreArrayOutputStream.ToString (String Charset)..

It doesn't have this function. I am using JDk1.7 and it should be supported.
I am using Netbean in windoews 7.

```
PrintStream co1=new PrintStream(new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream());
System.setOut(co1);
StatsUtil.submit(command);
co1.flush();
co1.close();
co1.toString();//acceptted this but it doesn't give me the stream content
String t=co1.toString("UTF-8");//the compliers give me errors the method doesn't get any string parameter
```

Any help wold be appreciated.

Comment: Quoting javadoc: "All characters printed by a `PrintStream` are converted into bytes using the platform's default character encoding". So, unless your default encoding is `UTF-8`, you may have issues!

Comment: Please review the thoughtful answers given below and mark one as correct if it solved your problems.

Comment: So basically your code snippet does not do what your question is asking; your mistake is to call `toString` on `PrintStream` instead of the `ByteArrayOutputStream` that your question is asking about. Voted to close as non-reproducible/typo.

Comment: Please review the answers given below, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You need to call `toString()` on the `ByteArrayOutputStream` itself, rather than the `PrintStream` which wraps it.  Try using this code:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream co1 = new PrintStream(baos, "UTF-8");
System.setOut(co1);
StatsUtil.submit(command);
co1.flush();
co1.close();
String t = baos.toString("UTF-8");
```

Comment: Hopefully the default charset for PrintStream is UTF-8, otherwise chaos will result. To be sure, specify the charset in the PrintStream constructor.

Comment: I read `public PrintStream(OutputStream out,  boolean autoFlush,  String encoding)` since 1.4

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your goal is to collect everything going to System.out via the `PrintStream` and get it as a String in the end. Is that correct?

Assuming it is, for now, you are using two different constructs here. `PrintStream` and `ByteArrayOutputStream`. The `PrintStream` is the *hose*, while the BAOS is the *storage tank*. Think of the characters being written to as water coming in via the `PrintStream` *into* the `BAOS` tank.

When you are done, you are interested in the water in the tank, the hose has nothing in it.

That is why you need to get the bytes out of BAOS via toString.

Comment: Nice explanation, but isn't the hose usually used for spraying the water *from* a tank? ;-)

Comment: @laune :) The hose fills the tank in this case. The PrintStream writes *to* the BAOS. Please correct me if I am mistaken, and +1 if you like the answer and don't mind.